# JSP looping through a mysql table on a jsp and displaying it

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

While refactoring my JSP to query my DB, I had this table below being cycled through, so it would be displayed on the page each showing up as a new table row. I'm having trouble getting the table to display the table data inside of the table row information. Before it was looping and pushing the new table data in each one of these, now it's only pushing the first row of the table into the table, and the rest of the table displaying is out side of the table on the JSP. Can you help me fix this.
To start I have the table data pushed into a list of cars, and the connection all in one method. I am getting the data out through like the following.

```
    <table border="2">
    <tr class="tblHeader">
        <td>Car ID</td>
        <td>Year</td>
        <td>Make</td>
        <td>Model</td>
        <td>Color</td>
        <td>Availability</td>

    </tr>
    <%
        Table table = new Table();
        table.getTableConnection();
        List<Car> cars = table.getTableConnection();
        String renting;
        for (Car c : cars) {
            int id = c.getId();
            String year = c.getYear();
            String make = c.getMake();
            String model = c.getModel();
            String color = c.getColor();
            String avail = c.getAvailable();

    %>
        <tr>
        <td><%=id%></td>
        <td><%=year%></td>
        <td><%=make%></td>
        <td><%=model%></td>
        <td><%=color%></td>
        <td><%=avail%></td>
        </tr>
        }
```

Comment: May be there is something wrong with your data like char with accent? Are you closing the html table properly? Consider using expression language in your code to avoid java code.

Comment: `table.getTableConnection();` are you sure this returns the list of cars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to put your rows into the loop.

```
<c:forEach items="${cars}" var="car">
    <tr>      
        <td>${car.id}</td>
        <td>${car.year}</td>
        <td>${car.make}</td>
        <td>${car.model}</td>
        <td>${car.color}</td>
        <td>${car.available}</td>  
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to correct the html syntax. You need to use the table header tag `<th></th>` to specify column headers.

```
<tr class="tblHeader">
        <th>Car ID</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Availability</th>
</tr>
```

Regarding the data rendering part, i couldn't find any issue with your code.

Answer (score 0):

After working with the foreach loop and moving some minor changes, table was being closed, before the for loop was finished. The table data was being cut off at the table end. My fault, for not seeing this silly mistake.